# Creating a context menu on drag complete in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drag-and-drop, contextmenu

I am working on a node-graph-view similar to Maya's HyperGraph in which I can connect Nodes with drag and drop. Because the target-node can have several Inputs, I want to create a temporary ContextMenu to select the input as suggesting in the following mock-up:

http://www.pixtur.org/images/uploaded/0000/0696/large.jpg

I tried for quite a time to trigger the creation or opening of a context-menu. It looks like the Win32 TrackPopupMenu does roughly, what I'm looking for. Is there an WPF / C# equivalent?

Thanks
pixtur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to attach a contextmenu to a listview gricolumn header:

```
<ListView ... MouseUp="ListView_MouseUp">
```

In the codebehind i set the `ContextMenu` property of the list on the mouse up event, in order to show the context menu:

```
    private void ListView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject depObj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

        while (depObj != null && (!(depObj is GridViewColumnHeader)))
        {
            depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
        }            

        if (depObj is GridViewColumnHeader && e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            ((GridViewColumnHeader)depObj).ContextMenu = ContextMenu;
        }
    }
```

The variable ContextMenu refers to a contextmenu instance that i created bfeorehand, you could also create the ContextMenu in the Mouse event handler.
I'm not sure if this helps as I dont know how you do the drag/drop, but it is worth a try

Comment: Hi pivotnig,

oh, this is very interesting. After another couple of hours, I got the following code running:

Comment: [code]
                cv.contextMenu.Items.Clear();
                foreach (Input input in targetOp.Inputs) {
                    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                    item.Header = input.Name;
                    //item.Click
                    cv.contextMenu.Items.Add(item);
                }
                cv.contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
[/code]

In this case cv is a parent UiElement. However, now I fail to assign an temporary click handler to 'click'.

Sorry, but I fail to format code snippets to comment...

Comment: thanks for marking the answer, does it work now for you? if not and you face a different problem now, i would ask another question

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another solution:

In this example a button will raise a context menu with one entry ("Copy") on right click. If the "Copy" context menu item is clicked, a console output is generated.

```
[..]
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "SomeButtonName";
button.MouseUp += HandleMouseUp;
[..]


private void HandleMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var senderUIControl = sender as Control;

    var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    var item = new MenuItem();
    item.Header = "Copy";
    item.Click += (o, a) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Copy item clicked");
    };
    contextMenu.Items.Add(item);

    senderUIControl.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}
```